# How Can I Name a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've written a small example program to help myself understand Threads. I have two class files, as below:

DoBench.java:

```
package benchmark;

public class DoBench {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Benchmark bmark = new Benchmark();
        Thread Timer = new Thread(bmark,"worktimer"); // name doesn't work?
        Timer.start();
        doALotOfWork();
//      Timer.finish(); // didn't work? why??
        bmark.finish();     
    }

    private static void doALotOfWork() {
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
    }
}
```

Benchmark.java:

```
package benchmark;

public class Benchmark implements Runnable {

    long start = 0;
    String timerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

    public void finish() {
        long diff = (System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
        System.err.println("\n"+timerName + " took " + diff + "ms");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println("\nStarted timer " + timerName);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Started timer main
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

main took 0ms
```

I have two questions,

1. How can I give the Thread a name that it can access (worktimer)?
2. How can I access the finish() method of the Thread, not of the Benchmark()?

Answer (score 2):

The context in which `getName()` gets called is wrong.

```
String timerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

**Reason:** When the above code executes, the `Thread` in context will be **main thread**. Since the above code belongs to *initialization block* of your `Runnable` implementation, and since in `main()` you are initializing the `Thread`, by passing this `Runnable`, the **main thread** executes the initialization block of `Benchmark`.

So `timerName` gets the value of main thread

Call `getName()` from `run()` method like below

```
@Override
public void run() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println("\nStarted timer " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I give the Thread a name that it can access (worktimer)?

```
timer.getName()
```

> How can I access the finish() method of the Thread, not of the Benchmark()?

there is no method `finish()` for `Thread`

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue is

```
String timerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

which sets the timer name at instantiation time and it's the `main` thread instantiating this runnable at

```
Benchmark bmark = new Benchmark(); // currentThread() is main here
```

So, to fix the issue identify your `currentThread()` inside the `run()` itself

```
@Override
public void run() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println("\nStarted timer " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Also, note that since it's always the `main` thread that calls

```
bmark.finish();
```

it will always print `main`.